# form_for does not append the action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this **html.erb** rails code :

```
<%= form_for(:dash_action, method: :post, url: {controller: 'brokers', action: 'dashboard'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit("Suchen", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "change_status") %>    
<% end %>
```

When I check the generated HTML code, I see this for the *form element* :

```
<form action="/brokers" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

But I expect to see this as action: **action="/brokers/dashboard"**

Whats going wrong ?

......................................................

Here all brokers relates routes:

```
  get 'brokers/login_page'
  get 'brokers', to: 'brokers#dashboard'
  post 'brokers/dashboard', to: 'brokers#dashboard'
  post 'brokers/eval_login', to: 'brokers#eval_login'
  get 'brokers/logout'
  get 'brokers/edit_order_now'
```

Also when I do a  `url_for(controller: 'brokers', action: 'dashboard')` 
I got only : 
/brokers

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute route on the `form_for` tag, your route should be like this `dashboard_brokers_path`

```
<%= form_for(:dash_action, url: dashboard_brokers_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit("Suchen", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "change_status") %>    
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
<%= form_for(:dash_action, url: "/brokers/dashboard") do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit("Suchen", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "change_status") %>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't like this fixed path style, because rails job it is to generate dynamically the correct path

Comment: You can use raila rested path ie brokers_dashboard_path